# Formulario con PHP y Jquery ida y vuelta

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario HTML con campos para nombre, apellido, email, asunto y la caja de mensaje,  tiene un submit.

Quiero que al enviar el mensaje me muestre como un mensaje que ya lo tengo en un div si es true o false.

Ahora necesito ayuda con jquery y php, si alguien tiene el código para ese capricho mio se los agradecería :)

Comment: por favor lea [ask], revise el [tour] y mejore su pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [tour], puede 
tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link [ask].